# Opening another window in an Appcelerator Titanium-app doesn't work

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I've got basically 5 windows in my iPad-application (created with Appcelerator Titanium) and want to be able to navigate forth and back (a back and and a next-button for that purpose).
The following approach doesn't work. Nothing happens upon clicking the button.

The first window is opened in my app.js like this:

```
var window = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    url:'mainwindows.js',
    modal: true
});
window.open();
```

then in mainwindows.js I've got a button called 'next' which does this:

```
buttonNext.addEventListener('click', function(e){

        var newWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
            url: "step_1.js",
            title: "Step 1"
        });
        win.open(newWindow, { animated:true})
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create [NavigationGroup](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.iPhone.NavigationGroup-object) to operate your windows like that:

```
//root window for nav group — your modal
var rootWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    url:'mainwindows.js',
    modal: true
});

var navGroup = Ti.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({
    window:window //your window (mainwindow.js)
});

rootWindow.add(navGroup);

//event handler
buttonNext.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var newWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        url: "step_1.js",
        title: "Step 1"
    });
   navGroup.open(newWindow);
});

rootWindow.open();
```

Explore [KitchenSink](http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/kitchensink), there are lots of examples there, including NavigationGroup as well.

Comment: I develop specifically for the iPad (will add that to the original question), so I can't use Navigations Groups

Comment: You _can_ use navigation groups inside the iPad. See KitchenSink for iPad. NavigationGroup lies inside iPhone namespace because it can be used both for iPhone and iPad, this is a bit confusing but it is.

Comment: When I try to use it in the application I get Script Error = Result of expression 'Ti.UI.iPhone' [undefined] is not an object. upon execution.

Comment: what is your titanium sdk version?

Comment: @Hedge is iPhone enabled in your tiapp.xml?

Comment: @ NR4TR: I'm on SDK version 1.7
@ Brian: <target device="iphone">true</target>

Comment: @NR4TR: any alternatives to achieve similar behavior on android?

Answer (score 1):

here is an example with full source in my blog,

http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/4043980803/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-minimal-ipad-splitview

It uses NavigationGroup with iPad.

I would suggest doing clean on your project and a complete rebuild

Answer (score 1):

**Clean your project** and then run again. This most certainly solves "odd" problems that are completely unexpected. One of my favorites is:

> Result of expression 'Ti.UI.iPhone' [undefined] is not an object.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `var navGroup`, window should be set as `window: rootWindow`, not `window: window`